# A “Complex Number” equation problem

Tags: complex-numbers

> $2z^5 + z^4 − 6z^2 + z + 1 = 0$ where $z\in \mathbb{C}$

Can anyone give any hints on how to solve this?

Comment: You can type it into [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2z%5E5+%2B+z%5E4+%E2%88%92+6z%5E2+%2B+z+%2B+1+%3D+0) which finds three real and two complex roots.  It solves it numerically.  We know that in general fifth degree equations cannot be solved analytically.

Comment: You can try your luck at spotting some sort of nice pattern (*I don't see it at a glance*) and you can try your luck at spotting a root by inspection (*usually by trying small integer or gaussian integer values like $0,1,-1,i,-i,2,\dots$*) and factoring if you find such a root.  If you cannot find such an easy root, then you are probably out of luck.  While there are formulas for finding the roots for quadratics (*$\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$*) and even ones for cubics and quartics, there does not and can not exist such a general formula for quintics or higher.